# Star Rating Control in UIAlertController subview is clipped when centred - Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uialertcontroller

I am using [Cosmos Star Rating Control](https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos) and I am embedding it as a subview of a UIAlertController. I struggled to get this to look correctly, however I managed to get the look I was going for with it being centred and all, but now I believe the view for the Star Control is being clipped, as it does not allow selection of certain areas on certain stars, also when turning on `clipToBounds = true` you can blatantly see that it's being clipped. I am just not sure why or how to solve this. The code and some screenshots are below. I also tried using a custom alert controller that allows you to add a custom content view, but still suffered the same issue.

```
@IBAction func rateButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject?) {

    //Alert for the rating
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: alert.view.frame.width, height: alert.view.frame.height))

    //The x/y coordinate of the rating view
    let xCoord = alert.view.frame.width/2 - 95 //(5 starts multiplied by 30 each, plus a 5 margin each / 2)
    let yCoord = CGFloat(25.0)

    ratingView.rating = 0.0
    ratingView.settings.starSize = 30
    ratingView.settings.emptyBorderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    ratingView.settings.updateOnTouch = true
    ratingView.frame.origin.x = xCoord
    ratingView.frame.origin.y = yCoord

    customView.addSubview(ratingView)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save Rating", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: ratingCompletionHandler))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: nil))
    alert.view.addSubview(customView)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Image with clipToBounds Turned on:

[image]

Image with clipToBounds Turned off:

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion... make the actual rating on the page tappable. No alert-view needed.  The common resistance to this approach is the argument that what's on the page itself should be the average rating, but the counter is if *you* are rating it, wouldn't you only want to see *your* rating and not care about what others say?  This is how it works on Netflix for instance.  You see the average rating (in one color) then if you tap on it and rate it yourself, you see your rating (in another, brighter color so you know it's yours) from that point on, or until you clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing around, I noticed that the CosmosView was using intrinsic content size and only would be as big as the content it holds(the stars), which I think was causing the issue, so a bit of an ugly work around I used, that works for now, was just to assign it a new frame of a custom size like so:

```
//Make a custom frame
ratingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 60.0)
ratingView.frame.origin.x = xCoord
ratingView.frame.origin.y = yCoord
```

This still has the stars centred as above, but now they are all clickable and provide the correct rating value when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way that may help you:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: alert.view.frame.width, height: alert.view.frame.height))

//add this line here
customView.sizeToFit()

//The x/y coordinate of the rating view
let xCoord = customView.view.frame.width/2 - 95 //(5 starts multiplied by 30 each, plus a 5 margin each / 2)
let yCoord = CGFloat(25.0)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, unfortunately It is still be clipped with this solution

Comment: I have added 2 things here: `sizeToFit` and `xCoord`

Answer (score 0):

If **preferredStyle is .alert** and not .actionSheet. Based on the fact that we cannot legitimately know the sizes before the alert controller (view) is shown, I'd opt to do this (in Swift 3):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                if let sv = alert.view.subviews[0] {
                    let w = ratingView.intrinsicContentSize.width
                    let h = ratingView.intrinsicContentSize.height
                    ratingView.frame = CGRect(x: sv.bounds.width/2 - w/2, y: sv.bounds.height/2 - h/2, width: w, height: h)
                    sv.addSubview(ratingView)
                }
            })
        }
```

Note: Might have to make adjustments for .actionSheet.